# Deploy de angular en Hostinger , SpringBoot en render.com y el mysql en Hostinger --- ERRORES DE CORS

Tags: angular, mysql-workbench, spring-mvc

Deploy de angular en Hostinger ,  SpringBoot en render.com y el mysql en Hostinger --- ERRORES DE CORS

Al abrir mi pagina web en hostinger me da errores de conexión
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aclaro que tengo configurado en spring boot los permisos en @crossOrigin
y las peticiones de angular al back son las correctas ( las direcciones )
tambien probe subiendo la pagina a Firebase y funciona perfecto

Answer (score 0):

para solucionar ese error, debes crear un arhivo java llamado CorsConfiguration.java en la misma carpeta que tu paplication.java on el siguiente contenido:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class CorsConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("*")
                .allowedHeaders("*");
    }
}
```

Tambien te recomendaria que en cada controller agregues HallowedHeaders en el @CrossOrigin, tal que asi:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
```

Cambiando el * de origins por la url de tu pagina.

Espero que te sea de ayuda, saludos.

Comment: Yo le pondría negrilla a la parte de cambiar el `*` por el dominio del sitio, jeje. Si lo deja con *, expone el sitio destino a problemas de seguridad :)

Comment: Veo que no lo aclare bien, gracias, ahi lo corrijo.